# How to remove paramters in NSURL's query in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsurl, nsurlrequest

I use this string to build NSURL

```
https://123.com?p1=AA&p2=BB&p3=CC
```

and I want to remove the p1 & p2 paramter,just left the p3 only:

```
https://123.com?p3=CC
```

Is there any nicer way than the string compare&delete?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
guard let urlFromString = URL(string: "https://123.com?p1=AA&p2=BB&p3=CC") else {
return
}

var url = urlFromString
```

Get the url without query params:

```
var components = URLComponents(url: url, resolvingAgainstBaseURL: true)
components?.query = nil // remove the query
url = components.url
```

create a QueryParams dictionary :

```
let stringDictionary = [
"p3": "CC"
]
```

create final url :

```
 guard let newURl = url.append(queryParameters: stringDictionary) else {
                return
            }
```